# odoo v11 converter does not exist

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

all modules has been installed correctly since I restored it from a working backup.
the problem is, it doesn't read properly. does anyone know how to fix this?

```
2022-02-15 02:40:22,799 31154 ERROR tester werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/service/server.py", line 292, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 166, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 154, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/http.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/http.py", line 1295, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/http.py", line 1510, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/addons/auth_signup/models/ir_http.py", line 19, in _dispatch
    return super(Http, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/addons/web_editor/models/ir_http.py", line 22, in _dispatch
    return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 322, in _dispatch
    rule, arguments = cls._find_handler(return_rule=True)
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 84, in _find_handler
    return cls.routing_map().bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match(return_rule=return_rule)
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 238, in routing_map
    cls._routing_map = http.routing_map(mods, False, converters=cls._get_converters())
  File "/home/ria/olive/tigernixerp11/odoo/http.py", line 988, in routing_map
    routing_map.add(werkzeug.routing.Rule(url, endpoint=endpoint, methods=routing['methods'], **kw))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1197, in add
    rule.bind(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 681, in bind
    self.compile()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 731, in compile
    _build_regex(self.is_leaf and self.rule or self.rule.rstrip('/'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 721, in _build_regex
    variable, converter, c_args, c_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 689, in get_converter
    raise LookupError('the converter %r does not exist' % converter_name)
LookupError: the converter 'str' does not exist
```

restoring in another computer doesn't seem to have any problem butthis computer seems to be unable to read properly

Comment: What scenario that reproduce this issue? Are you trying to install a module to another computer?

Comment: @altela. I was trying to swap/upgrade a device but then when I restore the copy that shows up. but unexpectedly for me. an empty/freshly made odoo app doesn't have that error

Comment: so basically i tried to not only install the module to another computer, but the entire database

Comment: did you give a permission to module folder location? sometimes odoo cannot read the module if it doesn't have permission to write. if you are using linux you can set it from terminal by `chmod -R 775` or `777` (not suggested)

Comment: @altela i did, but nothing happened

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, did you tried to use another browser or clear cache?

Comment: @altelaeleviansyahpramardhika yes I did, I tried to use 3 different browsers and the result is still the same